# android:keyIcon not working on alphabets in Android customized keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am working on a customized keyboard. I want to set icon for each character in the keyboard.

```
<Keyboard android:keyWidth="10.000002%p" android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height" android:horizontalGap="0.0px" android:verticalGap="0.0px"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Row>
        <Key android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:codes="3423" android:keyIcon="@drawable/q_shifted" />
        <Key android:codes="343"  android:keyIcon="@drawable/w_shifted" />
        <Key android:codes="" android:keyIcon="@drawable/e_shifted" />
        <Key android:codes="4342" android:keyIcon="@drawable/r_shifted" />
        <Key android:codes="2344" android:keyIcon="@drawable/t_shifted" />
        <Key android:codes="324" android:keyIcon="@drawable/y_shifted" />
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyIcon="@drawable/u_shifted" />
        <Key android:codes="546" android:keyIcon="@drawable/i_shifted" />
        <Key android:codes="546" android:keyLabel="O" />
        <Key android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:codes="5345" android:keyIcon="@drawable/p_shifted" />
    </Row>

....
....
....

 <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:keyWidth="20.000004%p" android:codes="-101" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyIcon="@drawable/vv_english_on" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="14.999998%p" android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="123" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="20.000004%p" android:codes="32" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_space" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="14.999998%p" android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="." />
        <Key android:keyWidth="14.999998%p" android:codes="44,59" android:keyLabel=", ;" />
        <Key android:keyWidth="14.999998%p" android:codes="10" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_return" />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

The icons are not showing for the keys but the icons like space, del, shift, drawable is correctly showing.

Is there any additional settings needed or is it not supported?

My icon size is 42 * 50 and are placed under drawable-xhdpi.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why the `android:code` for `e_shifted` is null?

Comment: Will that be a problem ?
I will change it try again

Comment: The `android:code` is for identifying the key, like its id, but it has nothing to do with the keyIcon.